# var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(response);

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, parsing

I have this script

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
```

While response is a json string returned via AJAX. response has a value of

```
[
    {
        "value": "Michael"
    },
    {
        "value": "Murray"
    },
    {
        "value": "mfo91@aol.com"
    },
    {
        "value": "1941-06-23"
    }
]
```

How would I loop through all values?

Answer (score 1):

What you have there is an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) of [objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object).  Given the current structure of those objects, the following should work for you:

```
for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
    console.log(response[i].value);
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Daedalus/GQkd3/)

Answer (score 0):

This is just an array, so you can loop over it with any normal array looping method.  For example:

```
obj.forEach(function (elem) {
    console.log(elem.value);
});
```